# Is there a way to get protected meta fields through any of the available built-in WordPress APIs? (xmlrpc, wp-json)

Tags: custom-field, api, xml-rpc, rest-api, wp-api

WordPress has several APIs build in:

- [XML-RPC](https://codex.wordpress.org/XML-RPC_WordPress_API)
- [REST API](http://v2.wp-api.org/)

by default they don't return custom post types or protected meta keys.

I want to access the protected meta fields of a plugin. I tried to follow the examples given [here](https://journal.rmccue.io/351/the-complex-state-of-meta-in-the-wordpress-rest-api/) and [here](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/adding-rest-api-support-for-custom-content-types/).

I did manage that the wp-json API would return custom post types by adding this code:

```
/**
 * Add REST API support to an already registered post type.
 */
add_action( 'init', 'my_custom_post_type_rest_support', 25 );

function my_custom_post_type_rest_support() {

  global $wp_post_types;

  // be sure to set this to the name of your post type!
  $post_type_name = 'tribe_venue';

  if( isset( $wp_post_types[ $post_type_name ] ) ) {
      $wp_post_types[$post_type_name]->show_in_rest = true;
      $wp_post_types[$post_type_name]->rest_base = $post_type_name;
      $wp_post_types[$post_type_name]->rest_controller_class = 'WP_REST_Posts_Controller';
  }

  $post_type_name2 = 'tribe_events';

  if( isset( $wp_post_types[ $post_type_name2 ] ) ) {
      $wp_post_types[$post_type_name2]->show_in_rest = true;
      $wp_post_types[$post_type_name2]->rest_base = $post_type_name2;
      $wp_post_types[$post_type_name2]->rest_controller_class = 'WP_REST_Posts_Controller';
  }
}
```

But I was not able to include protected meta keys in the response.

I tried the following code:

```
add_filter( 'is_protected_meta', function ( $protected, $key, $type ) {
    if ( $type === 'tribe_venue' && $key === '_VenueVenue' ) {
        return true;
    }
    return $protected;
}, 10, 3 );

add_filter( 'rae_include_protected_meta', '__return_true' );
```

and the following code:

```
function custom_rest_api_allowed_public_metadata($allowed_meta_keys){
    $allowed_meta_keys[] = '_VenueVenue';
    $allowed_meta_keys[] = '_VenueAddress';
    $allowed_meta_keys[] = '_VenueCity';
    return $allowed_meta_keys;
}

add_filter( 'rest_api_allowed_public_metadata', 'custom_rest_api_allowed_public_metadata' );
```

but neither works.

Does anybody know what is needed so make such protected fields accessible through any of the APIs? Is there a working example anywhere?

Comment: Is your goal to include them with the default routes or just any solution like creating your custom route/endpoint just for this?

Answer (score 1):

To me, the simplest solution would be creating additional field in JSON response and populating it with selected post meta:

```
function create_api_posts_meta_field() {

    // "tribe_venue" is your post type name, 
    // "protected-fields" is a name for new JSON field

    register_rest_field( 'tribe_venue', 'protected-fields', [
        'get_callback' => 'get_post_meta_for_api',
        'schema' => null,
    ] );
}

add_action( 'rest_api_init', 'create_api_posts_meta_field' );

/**
 * Callback function to populate our JSON field
 */
function get_post_meta_for_api( $object ) {

    $meta = get_post_meta( $object['id'] );

    return [
        'venue'   => $meta['_VenueVenue']   ?: '',
        'address' => $meta['_VenueAddress'] ?: '',
        'city'    => $meta['_VenueCity']    ?: '',
    ];
}
```

You should be able to see your meta data both in 
`/wp-json/wp/v2/tribe_venue/` and
`/wp-json/wp/v2/tribe_venue/{POST_ID}`

Answer (score 0):

With the REST API, there's a `rest_query_vars` filter you can use:

```
function my_allow_meta_query( $valid_vars ) {

    $valid_vars = array_merge( $valid_vars, array( 'meta_key', 'meta_value') );

    return $valid_vars;
}

add_filter( 'rest_query_vars', 'my_allow_meta_query' );
```

This allows you to use a route like this to query a meta field:

`wp-json/wp/v2/posts?filter[meta_key]=MY-KEY&filter[meta_value]=MY-VALUE`

There are also more complex ways you can do it. Check out the source link below.

Source: https://1fix.io/blog/2015/07/20/query-vars-wp-api/